# Testbench and unconstrained std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, spi

I'm writing a testbench for a SPI interface. The interface is basically composed by four signals :

1. spi_clk : Signal clock provvided by the master
2. spi_cs : Chip select signal driven by the master
3. spi_miso : Input signal of the Master ( output signal of the slave)
4. spi_mosi : Output signal of the Master ( input signal of the slave)

   I've traced the SPI Bus with an analyzer and I get file that shows every operation performed over the bus. Each operation begin with the falling edge of the chip select and it end with the rising edge os the chip select. The file is :

> ```
> ..................
> 03fff57000000000
> 03fff57400000000
> 03fff57800000000
> 03fff57c00000000
> 02f0fffec0a3
> 02f0fffcfc0c
> 03fff54000000000
> 03fff54400000000
> 03fff54800000000
> 03fff54c00000000
> 03fff57c00000000
> 03f0fffc0000
> 03f0fffe0000
> 03fff55000000000
> 03fff55400000000
> 03fff55800000000
> ..... and so on
> ```

Each line represents a spi operation on the bus. My problem to write the testbench is about the length of the SPI operation. It's simple to see that the byte transfered in one operation is variable. My will was to use the functions ***readline*** and ***hread*** to get the value line by line and feed my module, for example :

```
process
        file miso_file : TEXT is in "TestBench/MISO_DATA.txt";
        variable miso_line : LINE;
        variable VAR_miso : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
        file mosi_file : TEXT is in "TestBench/MOSI_DATA.txt";
        variable mosi_line : LINE;
        variable VAR_mosi : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable mosi_good : boolean;
        variable miso_good : boolean;
    begin
        
        ... some code ...

        while not(endfile(miso_file)) loop
            
            readline(miso_file,miso_line);
            hread(miso_line,VAR_miso,miso_good);

            ...some code...

            end loop;
    
        wait;
    end process;
```

This code works when the line is composed by 16 chars ( 64 bits ) but when the size is different it doesn't work. Does anyone have suggestions ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once `hread()` has consumed the line you don't know how many bytes were originally in it. You need to save `miso_line'length` before calling `hread()` and then have your testbench use that to determine what parts of the vector to send.

Comment: Uh, right I can get the length, thank you so much, it should avoid a lot of problems!!!